# overloading << in class template with ifsteam

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

For some reason I can't find the right template function sign to overload my class template Arr with ifstream...(ofstream worked)
I'm having a really hard time figuring this out...

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <fstream>

template<typename T, int N = 1>
class Arr {
    T m_data[N];
public:
    Arr(const T& initializer = 0) {   //only for context
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            m_data[i] = initializer;
    };
    Arr(initializer_list<T> values) {   //only for context
        copy(values.begin(), values.end(), m_data);
    };
    ~Arr() {};                        //only for context

    T operator[](unsigned index) const {   //only for context
        return m_data[index];
    }
    T& operator[](int index) {   //only for context
        return m_data[index];
    };
};

template <typename T, int N>        //OK
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Arr<T, N>& v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        os << v[i] << ' ';
    return os;
}

template<typename T, int N>       //OK
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream &os, const Arr<T, N>& v)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
        os << v[i] << ',';
    os << v[i];
    return os;
}

template<typename T, int N>     // NEVER REACHING HERE
T operator>>(ifstream &os, T v)
{
     //not reading
}

template<typename T, int N>     //OK
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream &os, const Arr<T, N>& v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        os >> v[i];     //C2679 binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
    return os;
}



int main()
{
    Arr<float, 9> numbers({ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 });
    cout << numbers;             // ok
    ofstream outf;
    outf.open("myStat.csv");
    outf << numbers;             // OK(save numbers to file)
    outf.close();
    Arr<float, 9> numbers_load;
    ifstream inf;
    inf.open("myStat.csv");

    inf >> numbers_load;      // the problem here(explanation below)

}
```

**Note:** `numbers_load` is  `Arr<T, N>`  so  `inf >> loaded_players`  will call to
`ifstream& operator>>ifstream &os, const Arr<T, N>& v)`  but then a error will occur because the compiler can't find  `T operator>>(ifstream &os, T v)`  . Why?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: You know, you don't need to write separate functions for `std::ostream` and `std::ofstream`. The latter inherits from the former, so you can use polymorphism.

Comment: good to know, but why does it matters for the overloading purposes? what is the right sign to overload this operator?

Answer (score 1):

In your function

```
template<typename T, int N>
T operator>>(ifstream &os, T v);
```

there's no way to deduce a value for template parameter `N`.  (It works for the other functions taking a `const Arr<T,N>&` parameter, because the compiler can compare that parameter type to an argument type like `Arr<float, 9>` and deduce that `T` is `float` and `N` is `9`.)

So you could maybe remove the `int N` template parameter ... but it's a Really Bad idea to define a template function that says how to get any object type at all from an `ifstream`.  Many built-in types, Standard library types, and user-defined types define their own versions of `operator>>` saying how to get them from either a `std::istream` or more generally from a `std::basic_istream<CharT, CharTraits>`.  And adding in that overload, there would be some non-obvious results about whether any particular `>>` token uses the existing definitions or your new one.  And existing code which assumes it's using the ordinary `operator>>` might suddenly switch to using yours instead.

If you just want a place to define what to do with each element while inputting to an `Arr<T,N>`, define a function with an ordinary name for that, not an `operator>>`.

(Less broken, but still a shaky design decision, is the part where `os << some_arr;` does different things depending on whether the static type of `os` is a `std::ifstream` or not.  This is at least unusual.  And note that it might lead to situations where someone passes a `std::ofstream` to a function taking `std::ostream&`, so that inside that function, `<<` means the non-file version, even though the stream object actually is an `ifstream`.)